# How to solve scrambled code problem with VIM

Tags: linux, macos, vim, terminal

I was playing around with terminal themes where I probably did something with Vim. And now I am trying to open a file with vim in terminal and it shows messy code:

[image]

Comment: I think you should simply open another file which contains text rather than data and see that everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

That's not your code. You appear to have opened the executable generated by your compiler, thus the garbled text. That, or you overwrote the source file during compilation with something like

```sh
gcc src.c -o src.c
```

If the former, then just open the correct file.

If the latter, then your file is gone. Since you tagged [macos](/questions/tagged/macos), I suggest checking Time Machine for a backup. Also, if this file was under source control (eg. git), then you should still be able to retrieve it. For example, if you're using git,

```sh
git reset HEAD src.c
git checkout -- src.c
```